# Container view popover view programmatically

Tags: view, popover, uicontainerview

In iPad View I add Container View, after adding Xcode automatically create new view and connect to my main view with embed segue. Now in code I try to call this new view programmatically and cannot do this, I need to show this form with popover.

I try:

```
PaymentCashController *newPopup = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PaymentCash"];
[self presentViewController:newPopup animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This work but show new view in full screen but I need show with popover. I try many things and all not working (.

I try this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PaymentCash" sender:nil];
```

But receive exception SIGABRT

I try this:

```
    PaymentCashController *newPopup = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PaymentCash"];

    UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:newPopup];

    popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 400);

    CGRect popoverStartFrame = {50, 500, 100, 100};//Set the frame that you would like your popover to present from.
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect: popoverStartFrame inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Receive exception SIGABRT

Try this:

```
    PaymentCashController *newPopup = [PaymentCashController new];

    UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:newPopup];

    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:newPopup];

    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(44, 6, 111, 111) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Same SIGABRT

Answer (score 0):

You need to create UIPopoverController with your view controller and present the popover as shown below.

```
PaymentCashController *newPopup = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PaymentCash"];

UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] newPopup];
popover.delegate = self;
//set custom size you want for popover
popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 400); 
CGRect popoverStartFrame = {50, 500, 100, 100};//Set the frame that you would like your popover to present from.
[popover presentPopoverFromRect: popoverStartFrame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: I have error on this - UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] newPopup]; No visible @interface UIPopoverController declares the selector newPopup

Comment: You need to include the header file for PaymentCashController class in the class where you're using above code.

Comment: Also, you need to make sure newPopup is initialised correctly and is not nil. If it is not initialised, perhaps the identifier you passed "PaymentCash" is not same as set in storyboard for PaymentCashController.

Comment: No, I include PaymentCashController and steel same error, but what is popover in your example ? I don't have that variable.

Comment: UIPopoverController is the class defined in UIKit framework used to create and display popover you needed

Comment: I try all from internet and always get SIGABRT

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Many experiments and now all working:

1. Remove all segue to my popover View in Storyboard. Do it freeform and change size.
2. Add to my main View new property

   @property (nonatomic,strong) UIPopoverController *popOver;
3. Set storyboard id to my popover View to "PaymentCash".
4. In any action on my View to show my popover View add this code:

   ```
   PaymentCashController *PopoverView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PaymentCash"];
   self.popOver =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:PopoverView];
   CGRect popoverStartFrame = {1,500,200,1};
   [self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:popoverStartFrame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
   ```

Only one problem after this, popover View show in no correct place but this another question.